# Modify data retrieval macro

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel, web-scraping

I have the below code that pulls a table from two pages that require a login. The code opens IE, goes to the login page, puts in the credentials, then pulls the 2 tables.

However, if IE is already logged in with a user, it directly takes you to this page (and thus the code errors out because there is no login fields):
https://www.example.com/taskprocessing/manage.jsp

I need to add an IF statement that if it lands on this page, to click on this link to log out, then proceed with logging in with the credentials:
https://www.example.com/taskprocessing/logout.jsp

```
Sub GetTable()

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "https://www.example.com/taskprocessing/login.jsp"
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        .Document.all.Item("Username").Value = "username123"
        .Document.all.Item("Password").Value = "password123"
        .Document.forms(0).submit
    End With


With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"URL;https://www.example.com/taskprocessing/report_pending_tasks.jsp", Destination:=Range("J1"))


        .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False


    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://www.example.com/taskprocessing/report_task_processing_stats.jsp", Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = """user"""
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With


End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You could check for a) `ie.locationUrl` b) `ie.getElementsByTagName("forms")(0).name` c) `ie.document.title`. There must be any number of differences between the two pages.

Comment: The details are sort of unclear, but you may try instead of adding IF statement just to add code block trying to force the log out first regardless of the status (with proper error handling if it fail).

Answer (score 0):

You can just skip the login process if not needed. To do this, you might re-structure your top-code as follows:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "https://www.example.com/taskprocessing/login.jsp"
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        On Error Resume Next 'this will help to understand if there was an error when trying retrieving the UserName field
        Set userField = .Document.getElementById("Username")
        If Err.Number = 0 Then 'if there was no error when trying to search for the username...
            .Document.all.Item("Username").Value = "username123"
            .Document.all.Item("Password").Value = "password123"
            .Document.forms(0).submit
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0 'turn-off the error handling once again
End With
```

The lines I added are:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

...to avoid the code breaking if there's an error when looking for a non-existing element;

```
Set userField = .Document.getElementById("Username")
```

...to see if the page is logged-in or logged-out. If it's logged-out, there will be no error while doing this. If it is not, then this will cause a "object does not exist error".

```
If Err.Number = 0 Then
```

...so if there was no error while doing this, we proceed with the login... otherwise we just go and keep on doing what we were doing.

```
On Error GoTo 0
```

...finally, we turn off the error handling so if there's any other error in the page you will keep on being informed regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I needed it to log out, so I added an Else statement.

```
On Error Resume Next 'this will help to understand if there was an error when trying retrieving the UserName field
        Set userField = .Document.getElementById("Username")

        If Err.Number = 0 Then 'if there was no error when trying to search for the username...
        .Document.all.Item("Username").Value = "username123"
        .Document.all.Item("Password").Value = "password123"
        .Document.forms(0).submit

        Else
        .Navigate "https://www.example.com/taskprocessing/logout.jsp"
        Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        .Document.all.Item("Username").Value = "username123"
        .Document.all.Item("Password").Value = "password123"
        .Document.forms(0).submit

        End If
        On Error GoTo 0 'turn-off the error handling once again
```